# Limit composition

Tags: calculus

If I am given the following graph, how do I compute the limit of x->2 of f(f(x))?

I tried to "[compose](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html)" the limits, but lim x->2 f(x) is 1, but then f is not continuous at 1, so the limit DNE? Is that right?

[image]

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that is not correct. From the graph, no matter how $x$ approaches $2$, $f(x)$ will approach $1$ *from below*. Therefore, to find the limit of $f(f(x))$, you want the *one-sided limit* of $f$ at $1$, which does exist and can be seen on the graph to be $-1$.

Comment: Great, thanks! I think that then I can also use this "from above" notion to solve the same limit as x approaches -1 (and get the answer being 2). But what about as x approaches 4? Then the above/below/left/right limits all go to 1, and it's not clear which one-sided limit to use

Comment: @MikeS: Draw a graph of $f(f(x))$ for $x$ between $3.5$ and $4.5$, and you will be enlightened.

Comment: @MikeS: Wait, how do you get 2 for $\lim_{x\to -1}f(f(x))$?

Comment: Since as x goes to -1, f(x) gores to 1 from above. so the limit is the limit of f(x) for x going to 1 from above?

Comment: @MikeS: Yes. But how does that become $2$?

Comment: I think I just made the mistake of using the defined point at x=1. looking back it should be 0?

Comment: @MikeS: Yes. Yes it should.

Answer (score 4):

As $x \to 2$ from the left, $f(x) \to 1$ from below; therefore, $$\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(f(x)) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = -1$$

But as $x \to 2^+$, we have the exact same behavior: $f(x)$ approaches $1$ from below, so the limit is again $-1$. It's possible to make such limit computations since $f$ is continuous on an interval to the left of $1$.